# How to parse and display JSON data in View using .NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, json.net

How can I display the JSON response below (received from a REST API) and display it in my View (MVC) in a filtered way?

As a solution I tried to create Models for it, see the result below, but the issue is that I can't filter the fields in the View display (for example, I only want to display the search results page for "SiteName" and ignore the other ones). Also I think it would be better to have a Dictionary<string, string> instead of a List with Key and Values, but JSON deserializer restricts me in this, since I use the following line to translate JSON to the model:

```
Models.Root convertedToModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Root>(jsonData);
```

I also tried to use the ViewData but keep getting a NullReferenceException.
Any suggestions for a better way to display the JSON data in the View on a filtered way?

```
{
    "Results": {
        "Rows": [{
                "Cells": [{
                        "Key": "Title",
                        "Value": "Some Document - 1234 ABC",
                        "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                    },
                    {
                        "Key": "Path",
                        "Value": "https: //contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/shipments/Shared documents/Some Document - 1234 ABC.pdf",
                        "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                    },
                    {
                        "Key": "SiteName",
                        "Value": "https: //contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/shipments",
                        "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Cells": [{
                        "Key": "Title",
                        "Value": "Some Document - 9432 XYZ",
                        "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                    },
                    {
                        "Key": "Path",
                        "Value": "https: //contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/shipments/Shared documents/Some Document - 9432 XYZ.pdf",
                        "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                    },
                    {
                        "Key": "SiteName",
                        "Value": "https: //contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/shipments",
                        "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                    }

                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "TotalResult": 2
}
```

Created the Model based on the JSON Data:

```
    public class Cell
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string ValueType { get; set; }
    }
 
    public class Row
    {
        public List<Cell> Cells { get; set; }
    }
 
    public class Results
    {
        public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
    }
 
    public class Root
    {
        public Results Results { get; set; }
        public int TotalResult { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model.ToList())
    {
        <tr>
            @foreach (var cellItem in item.Cells)
            {
                <th>@cellItem.Key</th>
            }
        </tr>
 
        <tr>
            @foreach (var cellItem in item.Cells)
            {
                <td>@cellItem.Value</td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: this is a great tool : https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonObject.htm

Comment: Your provided json does not seem to be a valid json, according to: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if the Cells's key format is always same, I suggest you could do a convert inside your controller and then pass the new created viewmodel to the MVC view.

For example, you could pass a new model List.

The result makeup:

```
public class Result
{
    public String Path { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
   public String SiteName { get; set; }
   //if it contains new cell you could add some new property
}
```

Then you could write a convert method to use foreach or else to convert this Root to `List<Result>`.